# Installing the DIRAC framework ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement `DIRAC3` in my `iOS 7` project using `Xcode 5.1`

I added the files and included the supporting frameworks (`Accelerate.framework, CoreAudio.framework, AudioToolbox.framework, AVFoundation.framework, MediaPlayer.framework and CoreMedia.framework`) but I'm still receiving a linker error:

```
ignoring file /Users/me/Downloads/--DIRAC3LE--/Dirac3-Mobile/Common Files/src/libDIRAC_iOS4-fat.a, missing required architecture arm64
```

Does anybody know what I might have done wrong or why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I think the current DIRAC3LE library for iOS is 32-bit only. Try removing `arm64` as an architecture.

1. Go to your target's **Build Settings**.
2. Look in the **Architectures** section.
3. In the setting for **Architectures**, change `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)`.
4. In the setting for **Valid Architectures**, remove the line `arm64`.

Hopefully this should work.

Comment: After doing above.....                                                                                   **No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386).**